# Unable to install Native iOS application in iphone 4s with having iOS 7.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I'm not able to install application in 4s Device  that has got iOS 7.0.2 in it. it gets install in it successfully. But after clicking on it, it keeps saying installing and nothing happens.

The application is developed using Xcode 4.5.2.

please help. unable to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run the app using Xcode - as in, running it off the device?  Or are you archiving for Ad-Hoc Distribution and attempting to then install the .ipa?
Regardless, you check the device's console to see if there are any errors reported while installing.

Comment: i'm trying to install .ipa file

Comment: Make sure that when exporting it, you sign the app with a provisioning profile specifically for your app.  You cannot use a profile that is set as a wildcard like you used to.  This was screwing me up for a while before I figured it out.  I ended up going and generating a new distribution profile specifically for the app - my old one was a wildcard.  It should say "<profileName> (from '<company name>', for '<app name>'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need new Xcode 5.0 to work with iOS 7.

Comment: Not strictly true.  You need Xcode 5 to run off a device via Xcode.  If you archive and put the app up for Ad-Hoc Distribution though, you can do so with Xcode 4.5.2 and it should run fine.

Comment: @Doc even better, once you run an app on a iOS 7 device you can then use Xcode 4.6.3, on the same machine, to debug apps on iOS 7.

Comment: I don't understand why someone down vote this solution.It worked well for me. What I did was change my Xcode did all the changes that were required for ios7 and it worked well.